# PowerShell command to check the connection between IPaddress and port in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working with PowerShell scripting on Windows Server 2012 R2. I was checking on the test connection of a machine with port. The following PowerShell command is working:

```
Test-NetConnection localhost -Port 445
```

This command along with `-InformationLevel` was returning either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the result. This is exactly what I wanted.

I need to run the same check on Windows Server 2008 R2. I understood that `Test-NetConnection` command will not work on Server 2008. I couldn't find any other commands to check the connection between machineIP and port and return whether `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Can anyone please suggest an alternative PowerShell command for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Network port access and display useful message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566052/how-to-check-network-port-access-and-display-useful-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script from [TechNet Script Center](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/97119ed6-6fb2-446d-98d8-32d823867131) from Boe Prox.

There are many [variants](http://poshcode.org/6442) out there that make use of the `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` and `System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient` [.Net classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) using either the `Connect` or `BeginConnect` methods.

Comment: I wanted the check IP address connection with the port. So I have done the following and it worked.
$tcpobject = new-Object system.Net.Sockets.TcpClient             
$connect = $tcpobject.BeginConnect($computer,$port,$null,$null) 
#Configure timeout before quitting
$wait = $connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000,$false) 

Check [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/37b3fc73-4c91-4a26-bd75-4156bcb96cce/how-to-controll-slow-response-times-for-negative-when-using-tcpobject-newobject?forum=winserverpowershell) for the full answer

Answer (score 0):

You can NetStat Tool
Read More about NetStat [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490947.aspx)