# Monitoring SQL service on a remote computer and start or stop a local service based on the result

Tags: powershell

I have a local service which interacts with a SQL database.

This service stays up when SQL database goes down.

What I need is a PowerShell script that checks the remote SQL service and based on the result it must start or stop the local service.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: See [Get-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if SQL server port is open on a remote host. 
See this answer for details about how to do this [How to check Network port access and display useful message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566052/how-to-check-network-port-access-and-display-useful-message)
The port number is depending on SQL server you're using. For example, for MS SQL default port is 1433 and for MySQL - 3306.