# Jenkins PowerShell: Start-Process with Passthru returns a different process ID when executed in Jenkins but not on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm experiencing a weird scenario where I want to open a .rdp file and get its Process ID on a Jenkins Pipeline.

My PowerShell Script (which based from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55360440/13726696)):

```
$app = Start-Process "$env:windir\system32\mstsc.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\Users\AzureUser\Desktop\MyRDP.rdp /h:900 /w:1600" -WindowStyle Minimized -PassThru

Write-Host $app.id
```

When I ran this on PowerShell it works as expected. However, when I tried to execute this script on a Jenkins Pipeline, it opens the .rdp file but returns a different process ID.

Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSgQM.png) of the result.

I also tried enclosing it in an `Invoke-Command` to make sure that it runs on a 64-bit Powershell but it did not change a thing.

I'm wondering what might be the other possible cause of this. Any help is going to be appreciated. :)

Comment: I still wasn't able to look for solutions as of today :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just simple. I will post my answer anyway incase anyone might encounter the same problem I have. You just need to make sure that Jenkins runs on 64-bit. That's all and worked like a charm.